# Date Formating Mobile Flex Project

Tags: flash, apache-flex, mobile, adobe

I have a mobile app that gets a rss feed. The date on the rss feed displays Fri, 28 Oct 2011 17:30:00 GMT and I would like that to render as a short date in cst time standard dd/mm/yyyy and time. The code for my app is below. any help would be great This is the first time working with Adobe Flash Builder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:ns1="*"
        backgroundColor="#74171E" title="Mediacom 2 / Paulbunyan 32"
        viewActivate="refresh()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function getData():void
            {
                getDataResult.token = iCTVChannel232.getData();
            }
            public function refresh(): void {
                getData();
            } 
        ]]>


    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:CallResponder id="getDataResult"/>
        <ns1:ICTVChannel232 id="iCTVChannel232"/>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:DataGrid id="dataGrid" left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="10">
        <s:columns>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="pubDate" width="65" headerText="Date"></s:GridColumn>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="title" headerText="Title"></s:GridColumn>
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:columns>
        <s:AsyncListView list="{getDataResult.lastResult}"/>

    </s:DataGrid>
    <s:actionContent>
        <s:Button icon="@Embed('/assets/refreshico.png')"
                  click="Object(navigator.activeView).refresh()"/>
    </s:actionContent>

</s:View>
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the date I think I would do something like this (admittedly it might not be the best way!):

```
//Making the Strings
private var getFeed:String = somehowGetRSSFeed();

private var theDateString:String = getMonth() +
                                "/" + 
                           getDay() + 
                                "/" +                                  
                           getYear();

//gets the month from the position of 9 and out to three places and make it a number
public function getMonth()
{
    switch(getFeed.substr(9, 3).toUpper())
    {
        case "JAN"
        {
            return "01";
        }
        .
        .
        .
        case "DEC"
        {
            return "12";
        }

    }
}

public function getDay()
{
    return getFeed.substr(5, 2);
}

public function getYear()
{
    return getFeed.substr(12, 4);
}
```

I think this would work.  You'd have to make changes where I made shortcuts, but I think you can figure it out.

Also, I'm not certain I actually put the correct position in for the strings, so you might have to change those.

Comment: I at a loss with this I have tried to add the code to <fx:Script> and it gets errors all over the place. Keep in mind I am new to Flex mobile and need help.

Comment: I also have a LIST setup of same feed but still date proble. I have tried this 2 ways.